# Intellij IDEA and Spring Dependency Injection

Tags: java, intellij-idea

While building an application with Java I often find myself adding a new dependency to a service.
Something like:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;

public class MyService {
    SomeDependency someDependency;
    @Inject
    public MyService (SomeDependency someDependency) {
         this.someDependency = someDependency;
    }
}
```

Every time that I need to add a new dependency I need to add it to the list of available variables, to the injected constructor and to the code inside the constructor.

However, all this can be inferred by the name of the class.

Is there some Intellij Plugin, smart macro or annotation that can automate this?

Comment: Why not simply use `@Inject` on the member variable instead of using a constructor based injection? Other than assignment, do you perform additional checks? If you are using `Lombok`, you can add `@AllArgsConstructor` annotation to the intended service and get rid of your constructor all together. Note that Spring does not need `@Inject` annotation on the constructor with all arguments (starting with Spring 5)

Comment: There are [Live Templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-live-templates.html) snippets you can create.

Comment: Why would you use a plugin for that? If you are using Spring > 2.5 , just use Autowired annotation. And you do not need to inject them in constructor. If you will, you may use a plugin like Lombok as @Prashant said.

Comment: There is no such annotation in Spring.

Comment: @Prashant AllArgsConstructor is pretty close to what I want, but hinders me from having other variables.
If I set Inject in the variables that I'm interested without the constructor I get an error that the variables might not be initialized (they are final)

Comment: @Andrey Live templates could work, but I don't know if it is possible to modify code that already exists. Say, you start the live template to add dependency, it requires the class, adds the variable with the same type and on completion it adds the info in the constructor that already exists.
I mean, adding a live template that adds the variable "and" the whole constructor should be easy, but dealing with an already existing constructor I'm not sure if it is possible

Comment: IntelliJ can do all this for you. Add a constructor parameter by typing "SD<ctrl-space>". This will auto-complete the type. Then type "s<Enter>". This will autocomplete the argument name. Then press Alt-Enter and select "Create field for parameter 'someDependency' with your keyboard. And everything is done.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks, that what I was looking for (specially the part of quick action to add field parameter). If you post it as an answer I will accept it. The two last steps can probably be moved into a macro, so only relying on the type, which is most normally the case